# Progress view value change problems

Tags: swift, swiftui

I developed one edit page which navigated from List page. but when I add the progress View in this page, I'm expecting it can be implemented like this:

- I use **movie.grenzen** for progress view display.
- In Increment Progress Button action I need to do movie.grenzen + 0.1, then movie.grenzen as a result need to be back stored into Core data.

I got some problems:

- `if self.movie.grenzen < 1 {` criteria doesn't work. always out of range.
- Progress View doesn't change with value plused.
- After back to previous page, the updated value of **movie.grenzen** cannot be reflected as the other text fields.
- Save the change, cannot automatically go back to previous page.

**EditView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct EntscheidenEdt: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  static let DefaultMovieTitle = "An untitled plan"
  static let DefaultMovieGenre = "Genre-buster"
  @Binding var movie : Movie
  @State private var showAlert = false
  @State private var progress = 0.0
  
  private var adapterValue: Binding<Double> {
    Binding<Double>(get: { self.movie.grenzen },
                    set: { self.movie.grenzen = $0})
  }
  init(_ movie: Binding<Movie>){
    self._movie = movie
  }
  
  var alert: Alert {
    Alert(title: Text("Alert Window"), message: Text("Go for it! "),
          dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")))
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Section(header: Text("Enscheiden")) {
          TextField("Title", text: $movie.title ?? "An untitled plan")
        }
        Section(header: Text("Genre")) {
          TextField("Genre", text: $movie.genre ?? "Genre-buster")
        }
        Section {
          DatePicker(
            selection: $movie.releaseDate ?? Date.init(),
            displayedComponents: .date) {
            Text("Date").foregroundColor(Color(.gray))
          }
        }
        Section {
          VStack(spacing: 30) {
            // 2.
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
              ProgressView("Progress", value: self.movie.grenzen, total: 1)
            } else {
              // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            
            // 3.
            Button("Increment Progress") {
              if self.movie.grenzen < 1 {
                self.movie.grenzen += 0.1
              }
            }
            // 4.
            Text("Current Progress: \(self.movie.grenzen * 100, specifier: "%.0f") %")
            Spacer()
          }
          .padding(.all, 10)
        }
        Section {
          Button(action: EntscheidenWechselAction) {
            Text("Entscheiden!")
          }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: { self.alert })
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Entscheidung Wechsel"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
  }
  
  //need to inform user Save seccuss!
  private func EntscheidenWechselAction() {
    showAlert = true
  }
}
```

**MovieRow**

```
**import SwiftUI**

struct MovieRow: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @State var movie: Movie
  static let releaseFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
  }()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: EntscheidenEdt(self.$movie)){
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack{
          movie.title.map(Text.init)
            .font(.system(size: 18))
          Spacer()
          ZStack {
            Circle()
              .stroke(lineWidth: 10.0)
              .opacity(0.3)
              .foregroundColor(Color(settingByColor(grenzen:movie.grenzen)))
            
            Circle()
              .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(movie.grenzen, 1.0)))
              .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 13.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
              .foregroundColor(Color(settingByColor(grenzen:movie.grenzen)))
              .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
              .animation(.linear)
            
            Text(String(format: "%.0f %%", min(movie.grenzen, 1.0)*100.0)).font(.system(size: 9))
              .font(.body)
              .bold()
          }.frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
          .padding(5.0)
        }
        movie.releaseDate.map { Text(Self.releaseFormatter.string(from: $0)) }
          .font(.caption)
        Spacer()
        //Keep it for additional information
        //            movie.genre.map(Text.init)
        //              .font(.body)
      }
    }
  }
  
  //Setting up Circle foregroundColors with different "Grenzen"
  func settingByColor(grenzen:Double) -> UIColor {
    if grenzen >= 0.8 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 75/255, green: 125/255, blue: 45/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen >= 0.7 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 115/255, green: 190/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen >= 0.6 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 160/255, green: 225/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen >= 0.5 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 210/255, green: 240/255, blue: 185/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen == 0.5 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen > 0.3 && grenzen <= 0.4 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 110/255, blue: 110/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen > 0.2 && grenzen <= 0.3 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if grenzen <= 0.2 {
      return UIColor.init(red: 205/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    else {
      return UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
  }
}
```

**MovieList**

```
import SwiftUI

// swiftlint:disable multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure
struct MovieList: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  //private var movie:Movie
  // 1.
  @FetchRequest(
    // 2.
    entity: Movie.entity(),
    // 3.
    sortDescriptors: [
      NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Movie.title, ascending: true)
    ]
    //,predicate: NSPredicate(format: "grenzen = 1")
    //,predicate: NSPredicate(format: "genre contains 'Action'")
    // 4.
  ) var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>
  
  
  @State var isPresented = false
  @State private var selection = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TabView(selection: $selection){
        List {
          //Neue Entscheidung anlegen
          Section(header:
                    HStack{ Spacer()
                      Text("Neue Entscheidung anlegen")
                        .font(.system(size: 20)).bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                      Spacer()
                    }.background(Color.blue)
          )
          {
            ForEach(movies.filter{ $0.grenzen < 1 }, id: \.title) {
              MovieRow(movie: $0)
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteMovie)
          }
          //EntSchieden!
          Section(header:
                    HStack{ Spacer()
                      Text("EntSchieden!")
                        .font(.system(size: 20)).bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                      Spacer()
                    }.background(Color.blue)) {
            
            ForEach(movies.filter{ $0.grenzen == 1 }, id: \.title) {
              MovieRow(movie: $0)
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteMovie)
          }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
          AddMovie { title, genre, releaseDate, grenzen in
            self.addMovie(title: title, genre: genre, releaseDate: releaseDate, grenzen: grenzen)
            self.isPresented = false
          }
        }
        
        .tabItem {
          Image(systemName: "house.fill")
          Text("Home")
        }
        .tag(0)
        Text("Bookmark Tab")
          .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
          .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle.fill")
            Text("Bookmark")
          }
          .tag(1)
        Text("Video Tab")
          .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
          .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "video.circle.fill")
            Text("Video")
          }
          .tag(2)
        Text("Profile Tab")
          .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
          .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            Text("Profile")
          }
          .tag(3)
      }
      .onAppear() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
      }
      .accentColor(.red)
      
      //.navigationBarTitle(Text("Dream List"))
      .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                            Button(action: { self.isPresented.toggle() }) {
                              Image(systemName: "plus")
                            }
      )
    }
  }
  
  func deleteMovie(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    // 1.
    offsets.forEach { index in
      // 2.
      let movie = self.movies[index]
      
      // 3.
      self.managedObjectContext.delete(movie)
    }
    
    // 4.
    saveContext()
  }
  
  func addMovie(title: String, genre: String, releaseDate: Date, grenzen: Double) {
    // 1
    let newMovie = Movie(context: managedObjectContext)
    
    // 2
    newMovie.title = title
    newMovie.genre = genre
    newMovie.releaseDate = releaseDate
    newMovie.grenzen = grenzen
    
    // 3
    saveContext()
  }
  
  func saveContext() {
    do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
      print("Error saving managed object context: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

struct MovieList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    MovieList()
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `Movie`

Comment: @jnpdx hi please see my code here.

Comment: I still don’t see the code for Movie. Please pare down what you have to a [mre]